Correspondence between finite groups and Latin squares satisfying the quadrangle criterion
I was studying combinatorial algebra when a question came to my mind.
Let's first recall some definitions.

Given a finite groupoid (i.e. finite set S with a binary internal operation) and a total order on it (thought as a bijection between its set and the first n natural numbers), its multiplication table is the n x n matrix with elements in S having as (i,j) entry the product of the i-th and j-th elements of the groupoid.
A matrix is said to be a multiplication table of a groupoid if there exists a total ordering on it such that the multiplication table associated to it coincides with the given matrix.
A matrix is said to satisfy the quadrangle criterion if, for every indices i, j, k, l and i', j', l', k', if each entry of indices (i,k), (i,l), (j,k) coincides with the entry with corresponding ' indices (e.g. (i,k) with (i',k'), etc.), then also the element of indices (j,l) is equal to the one of indices (j',l').
A Latin square in a n x n matrix having entries in {1, ..., n} such that the elements of every row and every column are all distinct.

In some notes, I found out a proposition stating that every Latin square satisfying the quadrangle criterion is a multiplication table of a group. The proof constructs a group operation but the given matrix doesn't seem in general to be its multiplication table under any order. A priori from this proof, I ask: does the latter statement hold true?
I doubt it: for example, since a group always have a neuter element, every its multiplication table will have a row and a column with corresponding elements, whilst I think (although I don't know how to build counterexamples) that this may not in general hold true for Latin squares satisfying the quadrangle criterion.

Are you aware of this document ?

@JeanMarie Yes, I am, but it seems to me that it does not address my question (which, phrased using its definition, would sound like: "Is it true that every Cayley matrix is a balanced Cayley table?").
